# Laravel guzzle call not working, works fine in postman

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to do this post call in laravel with guzzle:

[image]

Here is my laravel code with guzzle:

```
$client = new Client();

$data = array('owner' => 'owner', 'license' => 'license');

$request = $client->post(
    'https://url.com/?action=identify',
    $params = [
      'un' => 'one',
      'deux' => 'two',
    ]);

$response = $request->send();

return $response;
```

For some reason I always get the error:

> cURL error 6: Could not resolve host

Comment: Please help, this question is not a duplicate